# How to fix CORS error while callnig Laravel on Homestead from localhost browser

Tags: laravel, cors, homestead

I'm having Laravel 8 running on Homestead (Windows 11 OS) and can call APIs normally from Postman but when I try to call any API from the browser (build using VUE JS) I get CORS error. here's my `Http/Middleware/Cors.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
class Cors {
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        $response = $next($request);
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');

        return $response;
    }

}
```

THis didn't fix the problem so I installed `fruitcake/laravel-cors` and modified `app\Http\Kernel.php`

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
];
```

It didn't work also so I tried to modify the cors config

```
'paths' => ['*', 'api/*'],
'allowed_origins' => ['*', 'http://localhost:8081', 'http://192.168.1.27'],
```

But still can't make API requests from the browser to Laravel on Homestead. Any help please?

[Update]

In the console I get

```
ccess to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://backend.test:44300/api/passport_auth' from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

[image]

Comment: What error so you get in the browser console?

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://backend.test:44300/api/passport_auth' from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score -1):

try putting these lines to your /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/domain.tld configuration file. Check here for more detail:
https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/1368#issuecomment-609668101

```bash
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With' always;
```

Comment: this file `domain.tld` doesn't exist in this location `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` I only have the mapped domains in homestead.yml file

Comment: You are not able to modify nginx configurations in your homestead setup?

Comment: tbh I would go with Laravel sail instead using docker, vagrant is kind of obsolete